# Access weights, biases in model - PyTorch pruning

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, computer-vision, pruning

To implement L1-norm, unstructured, layer-wise pruning with torch.nn.utils.prune l1_unstructured, radom_unstructured methods, I have a toy LeNet-300-100 dense neural network as-

```
class LeNet300(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LeNet300, self).__init__()
        
        # Define layers-
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features = 28 * 28 * 1, out_features = 300)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features = 300, out_features = 100)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(in_features = 100, out_features = 10)
        
        self.weights_initialization()
    
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.leaky_relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.leaky_relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x
    
    
    def weights_initialization(self):
        '''
        When we define all the modules such as the layers in '__init__()'
        method above, these are all stored in 'self.modules()'.
        We go through each module one by one. This is the entire network,
        basically.
        '''
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
                nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight)
                nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 1)
    
    
    def shape_computation(self, x):
        print(f"Input shape: {x.shape}")
        x = self.fc1(x)
        print(f"dense1 output shape: {x.shape}")
        x = self.fc2(x)
        print(f"dense2 output shape: {x.shape}")
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        print(f"output shape: {x.shape}")
        del x
        return None

# Initialize architecture-
model = LeNet300().to(device)
```

This has 266610 trainable parameters. To prune this with 20% for the first two dense layers and 10% for the output layer until 99.5% sparsity, you need 25 pruning rounds. The pruning is done with-
`l1_unstructured(module = fc, name = 'weight', amount = 0.2)`

Iterating through the layers is done with-

```
for name, module in model.named_modules():
    if name == '':
        continue
    else:
        print(f"layer: {name}, module: {module}")
```

However, for a particular module, how to access its weights and biases besides using-
`module.weight, module.bias`
?

The idea is to use a layer-wise (for now) pruning function as-

```
# Prune multiple parameters/layers in a given model-
for name, module in model.named_modules():
  
    # prune 20% of weights/connections in for all hidden layaers-
    if isinstance(module, torch.nn.Linear) and name != 'output_layer':
        prune.l1_unstructured(module = module, name = 'weight', amount = 0.2)
    
    # prune 10% of weights/connections for output layer-
    elif isinstance(module, torch.nn.Linear) and name == 'output_layer':
        prune.l1_unstructured(module = module, name = 'weight', amount = 0.1)
```

Bias pruning will also be included.

Comment: The question is unclear, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` parameter is the attribute name of the parameter, within the module, on which the pruning will be applied (see [documentation page](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.prune.l1_unstructured.html)). As such, you can provide either 'weight' or 'bias' in your case since you are focusing on [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) exclusively.

Additionally, you will read that `prune.l1_unstructured` will:

> Modifies module in place (and also return the modified module) by:
>
> - adding a named buffer called `name+'_mask'` corresponding to the binary mask applied to the parameter name by the pruning method.
> - replacing the parameter name by its pruned version, while the original (unpruned) parameter is stored in a new parameter named
>   `name+'_orig'`.

You can access the pruned weights via the `weight` and `bias` attributes and the original parameters with `weight_orig` and `bias_orig`:

```
m = nn.Linear(2, 3)
m = prune.l1_unstructured(m, 'weight', amount=.2)
m = prune.l1_unstructured(m, 'bias', amount=.2)

>>> m.state_dict().keys()
odict_keys(['weight_orig', 'bias_orig', 'weight_mask', 'bias_mask'])
```